# Laravel access url in RedirectResponse

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.8

I am using a payment package which returns an instance of RedirecResponse class, then the user is redirected to the payment page.

I need to use this in a mobile application. I don't know how to tell the application to open that paying page. I can't return the instance of RedirecResponse to the application, therefore I have to get the url of the payment page from the instance of RedirecResponse and then return it to the application, then application must open the browser.

The `TargetUrl` property contains the url but Laravel returns the following error while accessing this:

> Cannot access protected property Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse::$targetUrl

How can I get the url from RedirectResponse?

Thanks

Comment: did you try `$redirectResponse->getTargetUrl()`?

Comment: @NoOorZ24 It worked thanks alot. post as an answer to accept it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As confirmed:

`$redirectResponse->getTargetUrl()`

does the trick

Answer (score 4):

You can add `$redirectResponse->getTargetUrl()` something like this to get redirect response.